# How can I deal with actor translations and other "noise" in third-party motion capture data?

Tags: xna, motion-capture

I'm working on a game, and I've run into a problem with motion capture data. My team is using 3DS Max 2011 and trying to put free motion capture files on our models.

The problem we're having is it has become extremely hard to find motion capture data that stays in place. We've found some great motion captures of things like walking and jumping but the actors themselves move within the data, so when we attach these animations to our models and bring them into XNA, the models walk forward even when they should technically be standing still (and then there's also the problem of them resetting at the end of the animation).

How can we clean up, at runtime or asset-processing time, the animation in these motion capture files?

Comment: I heavily edited your question to remove queries about "how other games do it" (since that's not considered on topic) and to focus instead on how *you* can handle *your* problem, which is a much better and pretty interesting question.

Comment: However, it might be useful to say what format the motion capture data is in.

Comment: I don't know much about it, but I believe these animations usually have a root bone. Wouldn't zeroing out the translation data for that root bone do the trick?

Answer (score -1):

If your models wind up walking forward after you apply the mocap data, then write some code to subtract the position of the model's abdomen for each animation frame.  Then the model will stay still, won't it?

Comment: Remember that [this site isn't for discussions](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/about). When providing an answer you should address all aspects of the question and don't leave it open for follow up. Answer with confidence and if it's wrong you can correct it later. Right now, this answer seems more like a guess and a request for clarification.

Comment: As a scientist, one does not give an answer with confidence.  One always leaves room for the possibility that we don't know everything.  As such, if your policy is to force answerers to give the impression that they know everything, then I will be forced to leave this community.  EDIT:  I see nothing in the rules you linked regarding "answer with confidence."

Comment: Sounds more like a philosophical approach than a scientific one. There are many things we can be *reasonably* sure of, and I'm fairly certain that an answer to this question is one of those things. The scientific approach in this case would be to not answer at all, or clearly state your assumptions and give an answer in confidence based on those assumptions. As a Q&A site, yes, it's kind of an unwritten policy to know if your answer is reasonably correct. If you'd like to discuss it further, you can post in [meta](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/).